# Editing running program with infinite loop

Tags: clojure

In this (http://vimeo.com/14709925) video dude edits running program that renders `opengl` stuff in a loop.

When i run this:

```
(def a 10)    

(defn myloop
  []
  (while (= 1 1)
    (println a)
    (Thread/sleep 1000)))

(myloop)
```

then change value of `a`, re eval does nothing, value doesn't seem to change. I'm using `LightTable` IDE. Should i switch to `emacs`?

Comment: I don't use LightTable, but one possibility is that the reevaluation isn't taking place because it is done on the same thread as the running program. Try running `myloop` in another thread instead with `(future (myloop))` instead of `(myloop)` and then re-`def` your `a` after a few prints and see if it changes.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem! Pls create an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that the re-evaluation isn't taking place because it is done on the same thread as the running program. Try running `myloop` in another thread instead with `(future (myloop))` instead of `(myloop)` and then re-`def` your `a` after a few prints and see if it changes.

Note that (in current Clojure versions) all [vars](http://clojure.org/vars) are dereferenced each time they are encountered, which allows for this dynamic behavior, but re-`def`-ing *except* during interactive testing/experimentation/demonstration is frowned upon. See [atoms](http://clojure.org/atoms) and [refs](http://clojure.org/refs).

Another consequence of this behavior of vars is that dereferencing can impact the efficiency of performance critical tight loops. Where the dynamic behavior is not needed you might see the following idiom to capture the value first (note you shouldn't attempt pre-optimazation in general until bottlenecks are identified).

```
(def foo 42)

(let [foo foo] ; capture value of foo within scope of let
  (loop ...
    ; do something with value of foo captured before entering loop
    ... ))
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question - but if you want to mutate state in this way in Clojure, I think it is probably more idiomatic to use one of the constructs for state manipulation (for example, an atom) rather than re-evaluating a def.

This is especially true if you're likely to need multiple threads, which might well be the case if you're working with graphics.

```
(def a (atom 10))    

(defn myloop []
  (while (= 1 1)
    (println @a)
    (Thread/sleep 1000)))

 (myloop)

 (reset! a 9)
```